# Why is there no implicit operator from string to Uri?

Tags: c#

A lot of methods take a Uri in parameter, but have no overload with a string parameter.

It is true that it's quite simple to write `new Uri("http://smthg")` instead of `"http://smthg"`, yet I don't see the point of doing so. C# provides us with a powerful functionality: the implicit operator overload.

Does anyone see a good reason not to use it in this case ?

Comment: If you use string literal, you might accidently put invalid URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because not all strings are URIs, and implicitly casting one such string would result in an exception being thrown at runtime.

Well-designed operators don't throw exceptions.

From [Guidelines for Casting Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b63aadf(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Do not throw exceptions from implicit casts because it is very difficult for the developer to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit operators shouldn't throw exceptions. There are plenty of strings that cannot be converted into `Uri`s and will cause a [`UriFormatException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.110).aspx) to be thrown.

And also, where would you say the sensible dividing line is? There are plenty of types where the type has a single argument constructor accepting a `string` or where a `Parse` method is available. Should all of these be replaced with implicit conversions?

Finally, it's a *good* thing, at times, to force people to *think* about data types and to not throw away all type information all of the time and just work with strings.

Comment: Putting the exception thing aside, I would draw the line where the object is immutable and the only way to define a value for the type is a constructor that takes a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Same way that functions that require numbers or dates don't take strings though they can both be represented as such. Uris are arguably a strong type. In fact by your logic we'd need no other types but strings, and we know what a bad move that is!

Comment: He's not saying there shouldn't be an URI type -- he's saying you should be able to assign to it using just a string literal instead of a URI constructor.

Comment: Yeah I get that. My point is that everything can be represented by a string if you really wanted it that way, but we generally don't.

Comment: The difference is that a Uri uses a string (internaly). Moreover, the only two ways you have to create a Uri are from another Uri or a string.